# One main LinkedHashMap for all clients

Tags: java, multithreading, server, linkedhashmap

I have a ServerMain class with ServerThreads. Everytime a client connects 1 new ServerThread is created. I want that every client send a string[] containing a port and coords that are saved in a LinkedHashMap and then the server should send the clients the LinkedHashMap with all the ports and coords of the other clients. But it turns out that every client send the string[] to a different ServerThread so different LinkedHashMap. How can I make that every client sends to one LinkedHashMap and the server sends all the clients this LinkedHashMap?

```
public class Main extends JFrame {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JTextArea chatWindow;
private List<Integer> ports = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public Main() throws IOException {
    super("ServerConsole");

    chatWindow = new JTextArea();
    chatWindow.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(chatWindow);
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane.setBounds(0, 20, 596, 200);
    add(scrollPane);

    setLayout(null);
    setSize(600, 300);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);

    Socket s = null;
    ServerSocket ss2 = null;
    showMessage("Server Listening......");
    try {
        ss2 = new ServerSocket(3175); // can also use static final PORT_NUM
                                        // , when defined

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        showMessage("Server error");

    }

    while (true) {
        try {
            s = ss2.accept();
            showMessage("connection Established\n");
            ports.add(s.getPort());
            ServerThread st = new ServerThread(s);
            st.start();

        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            showMessage("Connection Error");

        }
    }

}

private void showMessage(final String m) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            chatWindow.append(m);
        }
    });

}

}

class ServerThread extends Thread {

private ObjectOutputStream output;
private ObjectInputStream input;
Socket s = null;
private LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> playerCoords = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();

public ServerThread(Socket s) {
    this.s = s;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        input = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO error in server thread");
    }
    String[] message = new String[] { "" };
    try {
        while (message[0] != "234124214") {
            message = (String[]) input.readObject();
            if (message[0] != null) {
                playerCoords.put(Integer.parseInt(message[0]), message[1]);

                output.writeObject(playerCoords);
                output.flush();
            } else {
                output.writeObject(Integer.toString(s.getPort()));
                output.flush();
            }

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void closeWindow() throws IOException {
    input.close();
    output.close();
    s.close();
    System.out.println("Connection Closed");
}
}
```

Comment: BTW without calling `output.reset()` the `output.writeObject(playerCoords);` call will pass the same references each time without updating it.

Comment: where should i put this output.reset()

Comment: You can put it before sending the object, but I would put it after as this would be very slightly more efficient.